# How to handle stopping of Terracotta server?

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache, terracotta

I'm using Terracotta and when I start Terracotta server, then I build my project and deploy WAR file on Tomcat. Now, when Tomcat working, I stopping Terracotta server and Tomcat continue work without Terracotta server.

Question: How to handle, when Terracotta shutdown and doing reconnecting in Tomcat until Terracotta not start working again. Thanks!

Comment: What error you are facing? any log copy paste etc?

Comment: Sorry but no clear idea of what you are asking here. You want Tomcat to stop when Terracotta server stops?